# Excel VBA Find Duplicates and post to different sheet

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, crash

I keep having an issue with some code in VBA Excel was looking for some help!

I am trying to sort through a list of names with corresponding phone numbers,  checking for multiple names under the same phone number. Then post those names to a separate sheet.

So far my code is:

```
Sub main()
    Dim cName As New Collection
    For Each celli In Columns(3).Cells
    Sheets(2).Activate
        On Error GoTo raa
            If Not celli.Value = Empty Then
            cName.Add Item:=celli.Row, Key:="" & celli.Value
            End If
    Next celli
        On Error Resume Next
raa:
    Sheets(3).Activate
    Range("a1").Offset(celli.Row - 1, 0).Value = Range("a1").Offset(cName(celli.Value) - 1, 0).Value
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

When I try to run the code it crashes Excel, and does not give any error codes.

Some things I've tried to fix the issue:

- Shorted List of Items
- Converted phone numbers to string using cstr()
- Adjusted Range and offsets

I'm pretty new to all this, I only managed to get this far on the code with help from other posts on this site. Not sure where to go with this since it just crashes and gives me no error to look into. Any ideas are appreciated Thank you!

Updated:

```
Option Explicit
Dim output As Worksheet
Dim data As Worksheet
Dim hold As Object
Dim celli
Dim nextRow

Sub main()
    Set output = Worksheets("phoneFlags")
    Set data = Worksheets("filteredData")

    Set hold = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each celli In data.Columns(3).Cells
            On Error GoTo raa
            If Not IsEmpty(celli.Value) Then
                hold.Add Item:=celli.Row, Key:="" & celli.Value
            End If
        Next celli
        On Error Resume Next
raa:
    nextRow = output.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    output.Range("A" & nextRow).Value = data.Range("A1").Offset(hold(celli.Value) - 1, 0).Value
    'data.Range("B1").Offset(celli.Row - 1, 0).Value = Range("B1").Offset(hold
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

**Update2:**

Used `hold.Exists` along with an `ElseIf` to remove the `GoTo`'s. Also changed it to copy and paste the row to the next sheet.

```
Sub main()
    Set output = Worksheets("phoneFlags")
    Set data = Worksheets("filteredData")
    Set hold = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each celli In data.Columns(2).Cells
        If Not hold.Exists(CStr(celli.Value)) Then
            If Not IsEmpty(celli.Value) Then
                hold.Add Item:=celli.Row, Key:="" & celli.Value
            Else
            End If
        ElseIf hold.Exists(CStr(celli.Value)) Then
            data.Rows(celli.Row).Copy (Sheets("phoneFlags").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0))
            'output.Range("A" & nextRow).Value = data.Range("A1").Offset(hold(celli.Value) - 1, 0).Value
        End If
    Next celli
End Sub
```

Comment: You haven't initialized `celli` but you should also avoid `activate` and `Goto`'s

Comment: Why not use If .Exists and then store that in another dict and write that dict's keys|values to the sheet in one go?

Comment: Use `Option Explicit` and fix up the declaration errors that it exposes.

Comment: @Brotato I added in `Dim celli` regardless of what I declare it as still end up crashing. I'm looking into other ways to make it work without `activate` and `GoTo`'s I've noticed posts mentioning its a bad habit, just unsure how else to code it.

Comment: @QHarr I am not familiar with "If .Exists" I'll look into that option! Sounds like it would make for less intensive code than what I put together.

Comment: It is method of scripting dictionary. If adding to another dictionary when exists in your initial dict you can use overwrite syntax of dict(mykey) = vbnullstring.... to avoid clashes if you have already added that same key to the other dict.

Comment: @AJD I added in `Option Explicit` there is some improvement. The program no longer crashes and lets me debug the code. On debug it highlights `On Error GoTo raa`. Seems like I might need to figure out something aside from `GoTo`.

Comment: I think you also mean  If Not IsEmpty(celli)

Comment: Done some updates that got things rolling using dictionaries. @Brotato if you have a link or some examples on how I can avoid using `GoTo` I'll work on incorporating it!

Comment: Sorry about that, I was more impulsive than I should have been. I don't think that you can get away from it in this case, but for future projects, they can usually be replaced with `exit`'s or good if statements.

Comment: I appreciate it, I was able to move away from the `activate` and initialize the `celli` with you pointing them out, thanks for all the advice!

Comment: Because you are now using `IsEmpty` you should not need the `On error` branches.

Comment: @AJD If I try removing the `On Error`  I get a Run-time error '1004' on line: `output.Range("A" & nextRow).Value = data.Range("A1").Offset(hold(celli.Value) - 1, 0).Value`. If I fully remove the `GoTo` I get a Run-time error '457':  on line: `hold.Add Item:=celli.Row, Key:="" & celli.Value`

Comment: @GarrettRincon: That is good that you are getting those errors. Points to something wrong in the code logic. Yes, remove the full `On Error Goto` line (otherwise you just have am unconditional `Goto`!). Step through your program, you will see that you are trying to add duplicate items to your collection. The good thing about using the `Dictionary` object is that you can first check (`if Not hold.exists(CStr(celli.Value)) Then`) and then add if it does not already exist. BY using `On error` statements like you have, you are getting wrong results but not finding out about it.

Comment: @AJD I added in the `hold.exists` and got things working! I also changed it up a bit to post the entire now of data. I edited the post with the newest update.

Comment: Only issue now is in hindsight I want it to show the original and duplicate, currently the code only pastes the duplicates to a new page. That might need to be a different topic though...

Comment: @GarrettRincon: Yes, new question - new set of [mcve] and new answers/knowledge!

Comment: @AJD Sounds like a plan! I'm still new to using stack, since multiple people really helped add to the answer. How would I mark this as answered?

Comment: @GarrettRincon: I have added an actual answer so that you can mark this as answer. Cheers, glad all the comments helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When developing code, don't try (or be afraid of) errors as they are pointers to help fix the code or the logic. As such, don't use `On Error` unless it is absolutely indicated in the coding algorithm (*). using `On Error` when not necessary only hides errors, does not fix them and when coding it is always better to avoid the errors in the first place (good logic).

When adding to the Dictionary, first check to see if the item already exists. The Microsoft documentation notes that trying to add an element that already exists causes an error. An advantage that the `Dictionary` object has over an ordinary `Collection` object in VBA is the `.exists(value)` method, which returns a `Boolean`.

The short answer to your question, now that I have the context out of the way, is that you can first check (`if Not hold.exists(CStr(celli.Value)) Then`) and then add if it does not already exist.

(*) As a side note, I was solving an Excel macro issue yesterday which took me most of the day to nut out, but the raising of errors and the use of debugging code helped me make some stable code rather than some buggy but kind-of-working code (which is what I was fixing in the first place). However, the use of error handling can be a short cut in some instances such as:

```
Function RangeExists(WS as Worksheet, NamedRange as String) As Boolean
Dim tResult as Boolean
Dim tRange as Range
    tResult = False ' The default for declaring a Boolean is False, but I like to be explicit
    On Error Goto SetResult ' the use of error means not using a loop through all the named ranges in the WS and can be quicker.
        Set tRange = WS.Range(NamedRange) ' will error out if the named range does not exist
        tResult = True
    On Error Goto 0 ' Always good to explicitly limit where error hiding occurs, but not necessary in this example
SetResult:
    RangeExists = tResult
End Function
```